# I want to open a popup on clicking a button showing an aspx page

Tags: asp.net

I have seen this in the West-Wind Toolkits where they have created their control called Hover Panel but i'm not able to implement it.So,is there another method to do so.

Answer (score 1):

you can use jquery ui dialogs for this.  Check out this [sample](http://blog.roonga.com.au/2009/07/using-jquery-ui-dialog-with-aspnet-and.html)

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at the [ModalPopupExtender](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx) as part of the [ASP.NET AJAX Control toolkit](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/Default.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

ModalPopupExtender is an advanced option for pop up.

but if you want to do it simply you can use simple javascript to open popup form on button click :

Here is the script :

function popitup(url)

{

```
     newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=200,width=150');

     if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}

     return false;
```

}

add this in your html source for button click :

onclick="return popitup('test.aspx')"

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Aarti's answer, you could open popup from asp.net code with  Page's RegisterStartupScript function.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterStartupScript("OpenPopup", "<script>popitup('PageToOpen.aspx');</script>");


    }
```